# Why multiprocess C++ gRPC server does not work?

Tags: c++, grpc, multiprocess

I spawn multiple processes, and instantiate a C++ gRPC server for each subprocess. All subprocesses bind to the same port, and start up without errors.

When I start up multiple clients simultaneously, the requests get processed by the last subprocess (different threads on the same process).
When I tried restricting the MaxThreads to be less than the number of simultaneous clients, some of the clients failed to connect.

**Here's my environment:**

```
Mac OS X 10.15.4
cmake version 3.17.3
grpc 1.33.2
```

**Here's the Server Code:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (argc == 1) { //Primary Process

        char *mArgs[] = {argv[0], "-w", NULL};
        boost::filesystem::path binaryPath = boost::filesystem::system_complete(std::string(argv[0]));
        binaryPath.normalize();

        int error_code;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            pid_t pid = -1;
            error_code = posix_spawn(&pid, binaryPath.string().c_str(), NULL, NULL, mArgs, environ);

            if (error_code == 0 && pid > 0) {
                std::cout << "Forked Secondary Process, pid=" << pid << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Failed to fork secondary process, error_code=" << error_code << std::endl;
            }
        }
        wait(&error_code);
    } else {  //Secondary Process
        std::cout << "Child process... Not forking again. Starting Server." << std::endl;
        ForkedProcess forkedProcess("127.0.0.1:50054");
        forkedProcess.start();
    }
    return 0;
}

class ForkedProcess {

public:
    ForkedProcess(std::string host_and_port)
        : server_address(host_and_port){}

    void start() {
        ServerBuilder builder;
        builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
        grpc::ResourceQuota quota;
        quota.SetMaxThreads(2);
        builder.SetResourceQuota(quota);
        builder.RegisterService(&service);
        std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
        std::cout << "Server listening on port: " << server_address << std::endl;
        server->Wait();
    }

private:
    std::string server_address;
    GreeterServerImpl service;

};
```

Comment: Start investigating your problem with using tools to identify issues in your code, tools are often better than humans at that. [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) is amazing, so is [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/).

Comment: To get help here, familiarise yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What behavior were you expecting?  The described behavior doesn't sound obviously wrong.